# uncaught ReferenceError,Calling javascript function through android application..?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, referenceerror

I am trying to call a javascript function setGameName() through android Webview Activity but it is throwing `uncaught ReferenceError:setGameName not defined at :1`.

My Source code is as follows:

```
webView2.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView2.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
webView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView2.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "AndroidFunction");
webView2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
webView2.loadUrl("javascript:setGameName()");
```

Html code:

```
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init() {
                console.log("====== I am getting called::===");
                var testVal = document.getElementById('playertextId').value;
                AndroidFunction.proceedFurther(testVal);
            };

            function setGameName() {
                console.log("====== Got the value===");
                document.getElementById('gametextId').value;
            };
        </script>
</body>
```

It is loading index.html fine but throwing exception at function call,
Please provide an appropriate solution..

Update:

```
i have found the problem the page is not getting loaded at the time of function call..(Since on giving a time delay of 5000ms it is getting called..)!!
```

But How do I implement it then..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

loadUrl is asychronous. That means it returns immediately before the page has loaded. So setGameName does not yet exist when you try to call it.

You can implement a WebClient with an onPageFinished method and call your javascript code there.

Comment: @ZeroflagL..Could you please eleborate how should i implement it..?

Comment: [here](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/) is good example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure but probably you need to put file:///android_asset/www/index.html on a webserver and then retrieve it. By default browsers don't let JS load from JS originating from Filesystems.

Comment: @gashu...It is not so..File is getting loaded and internal javascript functions are working fine. just a call from activity to js is throwing an exception..